# Jmeter share data from setupthreadgroup to normal threadgroup

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

How to share the list of lists variable from setupthreadgroup to a normal threadgroup in jmeter?

for instance if I have list1=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] in setupthreadgroup and same I want to use in subsequent thread group. How can we achieve this?

I am trying to save this using props.put('listOfData',list1) in setupThreadGroup and in normal threadGroup I am trying to access it using props.get(listOfData[1][1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this one:

```
props.get(listOfData[1][1])
```

to this one:

```
props.get('listOfData')[1][1]
```

`props` is just a shorthand for [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), see the JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

Comment: @Dimitri, Thanks for sharing this. If the length of list of list is heavy. Does jmeter throw any heap issues? Do you think this is fair good way to use it in my load test?

Comment: It does if it runs out of heap space